# Create a proxy within the iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, proxy

I have an app with an UIWebView (which is connected with a website); the user will navigate into the website. After that, I want that when the user open the app and there is no connection, the already visited pages will be accessible.

So I though that it should be possible if I create an internal proxy within the app: each request will be processed by this proxy (and will send the result to the UIWebView). Of course, the proxy should cache the web pages and, if there is no connection available, use the cached pages.

I prefer this approach instead of others (HTML5 offline cache) because, in the future, I will can set some feature to the proxy, for example "I want to cache all the pictures for the next 5 hours" etc...

Do you know if it's possible and, if it is, what should I use to do it?
Or... do you know if there is something similar already done (some Objective-C Proxy?) ?

Comment: For a simple implementation of this, along with discussion of how to build more complex implementations, see http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use HTTP caching mechanism. Can you set HTTP headers on the web server? If so you may set max-age for every picture or other resource on the website to keep them in cache for up to a certain time.

UIWebView will honor HTTP headers.

That is the simplest way but it is limited. There are certain cache size limits set by iOS. Large resources may not be cached or may quickly kick other resources from the cache.

Another way is to send your own requests for resources with [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and specify NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy flags. You may honor web server caching or you may override that. Caching is handled for you by iOS in this case. The problem is that you can't specify a proxy for UIWebView. That means you will have to manage redirections to your proxy by yourself. You will need to analyze website content and capture internal requests for images, CSS, javascript, etc.

Yet another way is to handle both requests and caching yourself. That is apparently the most laborious way but you'll have total control in your hands.

You may want to use [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIWebPageRequest-a-new-class-for-downloading-complete-webpages) or [ProxyingUIWebView](https://github.com/pokeb/ProxyingUIWebView) in your code or get ideas from their implementation for yourself.